# Dynamically create multiple sub-classes with dynamically named reference

Tags: python, dynamic, subclass, metaclass

I have a module (myMod.py) with an Object baseObj with a few methods

```
class baseObj(object):
    ....
    def doThing(self):
        ......
```

I need to create many subclasss,  normal way to do this would be:

```
class Foo(baseObl):
    pass

class Bar(baseObl):
    pass
```

etc.

But there there are a lot of these.

I have the names of these subclasss in a list

```
subNames  = ['Foo','Bar','Lorem',...]
```

I can create the subclass dynamically like so (identical to the above)

```
Foo = type('Foo', (baseObj), {})
```

What I want to do is something like:

```
for name in subNames:
    name = type(name, (baseObj), {})
```

To create a bunch of subclasss with the names in the list.

Obviously, this dose not work.

What I found on line was doing something like this :

```
registry =[]
for name in subNames:
    registry[name] = type(name, (baseObj), {})
```

Which will not give me the kind if API I am looking for.

What I want to allow at the end is:

```
from myMod import Foo, Bar

a = Foo()
a.doThing()

b = Bar()
b.doThing()

etc.
```

Is there a pretty way to do this?

Comment: See the duplicate; one of the options there is to use the `globals()` dictionary. `globals[name] = type(name, (baseObj,), {})`.

Comment: This still feels wrong somehow. Maybe you have a good use-case. If you want advice on a (possibly) better design, you can open a new question where you explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I am wrapping a JSON RPC API. The API publishes a dynamic list of objects to be manged which is the source of the name of the subs in my list. All the objects allow basic CRUD actions.  Kind like WSDL for JSON. I'll crate  a separate questions for that.